# How is a Macro Defined in Terms of Itself?

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp

How can LISP macro's be [defined in terms of itself](https://github.com/JeffBezanson/femtolisp/blob/master/system.lsp#L35)?  I saw a similar definition in LISP In Small Pieces.  I thought there might be a boot strapping phase where the body gets shoved into syntaxt-environment before define-macro is defined, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use *View git blame* on this line, you can see the commit that introduced the change. Previously, `define-macro` was defined in terms of the base language, using `set-syntax!`.

The commit replaces this definition by a definition that uses that previous value of `define-macro`, the one which was available from `flisp.boot` when loading the interpreter.